# Is it possible to highlight part of a river using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

As part of a water quality survey we need to display, color coded, the water quality of a river segment. We measure the water quality along the river at multiple coordinates, and we need to display the river with different colors between two consecutive measuring points.
Is this possible using the Google Maps API (or Bing, Openstreetmap, ...)?

Comment: highlight insense do you want to show color variation for rivers?  If so then you can use `satellite view` right?

Comment: Could you draw a translucent polygon over the measured section?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Comment: To further clarify, i want to create something like this: [Water quality map](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/figures/comparison-of-water-quality-in/comparison-of-water-quality-in/image_original)